# Update pytorch tensor in place using multiple slices without copying

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, slice, tensor

Doing some reinforcement learning.
The state of the game is a set of vehicles, each vehicle has their own set of vulnerabilities, and each vulnerability has as features: probability that an attack is successful, severity of a successful attack, and a flag representing if an attack has been successful yet.

This gives a batch of states the shape [batch, vehicle, vuln, feature]

The attacker action is defined as a subset of the vehicles in each state to be attacked.

The state transformation for a state-action pair is done by 'rolling a dice' and seeing if the attack succeeds against each vulnerability in the selected vehicles.

I have it working on batches of states and actions, but it's using a workaround

```py
import torch
num_batches = 4
MAX_VEHICLES = 3
MAX_VULNS = 3
MAX_ATTACK = 2

# example definition of a batch of states
prob_dist = torch.distributions.Normal(loc=torch.as_tensor(0.5, dtype=torch.float32), scale=torch.as_tensor(0.25, dtype=torch.float32))
sev_dist = torch.distributions.Normal(loc=torch.as_tensor(2, dtype=torch.float32),scale=torch.as_tensor(1, dtype=torch.float32))
states = torch.zeros((num_batches, MAX_VEHICLES, MAX_VULNS, 3), dtype=torch.float32)
states[:,:,:,0] = prob_dist.sample(torch.Size((num_batches, MAX_VEHICLES, MAX_VULNS))).clamp(0,1)
states[:,:,:,1] = sev_dist.sample(torch.Size((num_batches, MAX_VEHICLES, MAX_VULNS))).round().clamp(1,5)
print("states", states.shape, states)
# return states

# example definition of a batch of actions
# the attacker picks MAX_ATTACK vehicles from each state
priority = (states[:,:,:,0] * states[:,:,:,1] * (1-states[:,:,:,2])).sum(dim=-1)
attack = priority.topk(MAX_ATTACK).indices
attack_mask = torch.zeros((states.shape[0], MAX_VEHICLES), dtype=torch.float32).to(states.device).scatter_(1, attack, 1).bool()
print("attack mask", attack_mask)
# return attack_mask

# for each attacked vehicle in the state, each vulnerability has a chance of being compromised
next_states = states.clone()
attack = next_states[attack_mask]
probs = torch.rand(attack.shape[:-1], dtype=torch.float32, device=states.device)

success_mask = (probs > 1-attack[:,:,0])
print("success mask", success_mask)

## fails because of advanced slicing cloning the tensors
# next_states[attack_mask][success_mask][:,2] = 1
## what's a better way to do this?

# workaround: must rebuild the tensors despite the fact we have all the slicing information
success = attack[success_mask]
success[:,2] = 1
attack[success_mask] = success
next_states[attack_mask] = attack
print("next states", next_states)
```

example output:

```
states torch.Size([2, 3, 3, 3]) tensor([[[[0.3672, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.2386, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.5873, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.7048, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.5552, 1.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.4456, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.3886, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.3745, 1.0000, 0.0000]]],


        [[[0.0000, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.3182, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0357, 2.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.6474, 1.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.7376, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.6590, 2.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.6119, 1.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.7148, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.6434, 2.0000, 0.0000]]]])
attack mask tensor([[False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]])
success mask tensor([[ True,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]])
next states tensor([[[[0.3672, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.2386, 2.0000, 0.0000],
          [1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.5873, 2.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.7048, 3.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.5552, 1.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.4456, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.3886, 2.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.3745, 1.0000, 0.0000]]],


        [[[0.0000, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.3182, 3.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0357, 2.0000, 0.0000]],

         [[0.6474, 1.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.7376, 2.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.6590, 2.0000, 1.0000]],

         [[0.6119, 1.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.7148, 3.0000, 1.0000],
          [0.6434, 2.0000, 1.0000]]]])
```

Is there a better way than my workaround to achieve the `next_states` tensor given `states` and `attack_mask` ?